# Lottie Animation JSON crashes my code with no explanation

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, lottie

I am working on an app, and am trying to implement a Lottie animation. For some reason, each time it starts the app it crashes, but when I use a normal loader animation that's built-in it works perfectly.

```js
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import { globalStyles } from '../../../../theme/styles';

export const LottieAnimation = () =>{
  return(
    <View style={[globalStyles.center, globalStyles.horizontal]}>
      <LottieView
        style={{
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
        }}
        source={require('./49857-trodo-loader.json')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

That's that function for the animation, and I can't find anything specifically wrong with it. Any ideas? The JSON is valid and everything. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: How do you know that it "crashes"? What happens exactly? Which errors do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: That's the weird thing: there are no errors. The app closes. On the other hand, if the built-in loader works the app opens perfectly